# Is value of speed equal to the magnitude of velocity?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, vectors, definition, speed

For example: - suppose a body covers a semi-circle in $5$ seconds, then distance$=\pi * r$, where $r$ is the radius of the semi-circle. Displacement is $2r$ only. Then the value of speed is $[\pi * r] / 5$ while that of velocity is $2r/5$. Here we can see that magnitude of velocity is different from that of speed. Is it correct?

Comment: The displacement is $2r$ and the average velocity is $2r/5$.  How do you claim $\pi∗r/5$ is the speed?

Answer (score 7):

Instantaneous speed always equals the magnitude of instantaneous velocity (because the instantaneous displacement is small enough to be regarded as straight-line). In your example, you are comparing average speed and the magnitude of average velocity - and the two of them can be different as you have correctly calculated.